# Django query ORM to query based on primary key then get information from junction tables linked by foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I have a table which has a primary key and I want to query that table on that primary key. This links to 2 junction tables who are foreign key linked to my first table. Can I access all of the information relating to this primary key from all of these tables:

models.py:

```
class Variant(models.Model):
    variant = models.CharField(max_length=60, primary_key=True)


class VarSamRun(models.Model:
    sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='sample')
    variant = models.ForeignKey(Variant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='variant')
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='run')
    .... 
    more attributes
    ...


class ClinVarSam(models.Model:
    sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='sample')
    variant = models.ForeignKey(Variant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='variant')
    .... 
    more attributes
    ...
```

I want to query VarSamRun with some variables such as:

```
obj = VariantSampleRun.objects.filter(sample=sample, run=run).select_related('variant')
```

but I dont seem to be able to get any of the information from ClinVarSamRun from this object

I have also tried:

```
obj = Variant.objects.prefetch_related('variant__clinicallyreportedvariant_set', 'variantsamplerun_set')
```

but this again doesnt hold any VarSamRun or ClinVarSamRun object attributes

How can I get these out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated Answer*

I thought of a solution based on your comments:

```
variants = Variant.objects.filter(variantsamplerun_set__sample=sample, variantsamplerun_set__run=run).values_list('variant', 'variantsamplerun_set__sample_id', 'clinvarsam_set__some_field', 'clinvarsam_set__other_field')
for v in variants:
    print(v['variant'], v['variantsamplerun_set__sample_id'], v['clinvarsam_set__some_field'], v['clinvarsam_set__other_field'])
```

I think the values_list method may work well to achieve the query you were after.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

*Old Answer*

I think you're misinterpreting the use of [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), this will change the query made to the database when you evaluate your queryset, not return a variant.  Also, do you mean to use .filter or .get? .filter returns a Queryset not an object.

```
varsamrun_qs = VariantSampleRun.objects.filter(sample=sample, run=run).select_related('variant')
for varsamrun in varsamrun_qs:
    print(varsamrun.variant)  # This does not make an extra sql call to retrieve the variant object
```

This should make one sql query to evaluate the queryset and retrieve the related variant field, and then print each VariantSampleRun's variant.

If you want to be able to retrieve a ClinVarSam from a matching VarSamRun, you could add a property method to your VarSamRun model:

```
class VarSamRun(models.Model:
    sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='sample')
    variant = models.ForeignKey(Variant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='variant')
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='run')
    .... 
    more attributes
    ...

    @property
    def clinvarsam(self):
        return ClinVarSam.objects.get(sample=self.sample, variant=self.variant)
```

And then use this in the sample from before:

```
varsamrun_qs = VariantSampleRun.objects.filter(sample=sample, run=run).select_related('variant')
for varsamrun in varsamrun_qs:
    print(varsamrun.variant)  # This does not make an extra sql call to retrieve the variant object
    print(varsamrun.clinvarsam)
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks! I have obj = VarSamRun.objects.filter(sample=sample, run=run).select_related('variant') in my code, but with this obj - I could not access any of the ClinVarSamRun attributes that relate to this sample on this run... is there a way to do this using this kind of query or is it best to just make a new one (ie obj = ClinVarSam.objects.filter(sample=sample).select_related('variant')   *edit* is that ClinVarSam does not have 'run' attribute

Comment: I think you will need to do a seperate query to get the ClinVarSamRun's, unless there is a direct foreign key between varsamrun and clinvarsamrun.

Comment: No that is why I was trying to query via Variant, it directly links VarSamRun and ClinVarSam by the variant attribute, but the VarSamRun/ClinVarSams do not directly link - is there a way to do a multiple join query in django ORM: SELECT v.variant, vsr.sample, c.more_info FROM variant v JOIN varsamrun vsr ON vsr.variant=v.variant JOIN clinvarsam c ON c.variant=v.variant;

Comment: Ah, I see what you're going for, I'll think about it and may improve my answer.